# Qt/OSX WebSocket opening handshake timed out

Tags: c++, macos, qt, google-chrome, websocket

I just developed an Application in Qt that uses a WebSocket Server (QWebSocketServer). I did this under Linux and everything worked great, but when I ran the code on Mac OS I was unable to connect to the server from a webpage on Chrome.

The connection took ages, and I got `WebSocket opening handshake timed out` from Chrome after a few minutes.

In the end I went back to basics and tried Qt's example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-sslechoserver-example.html

Exactly the same.

edit:

After removing SSL and using non-secure websockets it works, even on the same port.

Chrome on the Mac can access a secure Qt WebSocket server on a remote (non-Mac) computer, but Chrome on a remote computer times out while connecting to the Mac (securely) - so it would appear to be something wrong with the Qt QWebSocketServer example. It works fine on both Linux and Windows.

There is a connection being made (because the web browser fails instantly if the application isn't running or is closed), but for whatever reason it isn't completing.

Any idea what this might be, or how I can go about trying to track it down?

thanks!

Comment: Is the Mac firewall turned on?

Comment: No - I checked that first :) I can actually make a connection to it with netcat, but it seems there is no response to anything that's sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As qt document(http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsslsocket.html) says: 
Note: Secure Transport SSL backend on macOS may update the default keychain (the default is probably your login keychain) by importing your local certificates and keys. This can also result in system dialogs showing up and asking for permission when your application is using these private keys. If such behavior is undesired, set the QT_SSL_USE_TEMPORARY_KEYCHAIN environment variable to a non-zero value; this will prompt QSslSocket to use its own temporary keychain.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be some interaction with MacOS's permissions system.

The first time you run the application and connect, the app will pop up a window asking for permissions to access your keychain (I guess to install the certificate).

If you close the dialog at that point, it won't come back, and it seems no QtWebSocketServer based programs will function from then on, until your reboot!